# xCode 4.6: 'PFEventTaps/PFEventTap.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using xCode 4.6 to compile and run Event Taps TestBench from Pfiddlesoft.  I downloaded the project and opened it in xCode.  When I try to run, I get the error:

Lexical or Preprocessor issue: 'PFEventTaps/PFEventTap.h' file not found.

I spoke with the developer of the test bench and he had me make sure that PFEventTaps was in the Framework.  It is.  Is there anything else that I might try?

Comment: you can download the Test Bench from here: http://pfiddlesoft.com/eventtapstestbench/.  If you can compile and run this in xCode, please let me know!

Comment: Actually the source code and the project are located here: http://pfiddlesoft.com/frameworks/.  Look for the source code link.